# Close batch file after launch a program

Tags: batch

I adopt this batch script to bring the already opened outlook program to forefront which works and the batch closes then. However the batch does not close itself when outlook needs to open newly. Please help where should be modified.

```
@echo off 
setlocal
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq Outlook.exe" ^| 
find /I "Outlook.exe"') do set pid=%%i
if "%pid%" == "" (
 "%systemdrive%\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft 
 Office\Office12\OUTLOOK.EXE" 
 ) else (
 cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" "%~nx0" "%pid%"
 )
 exit /b %errorlevel% 
 endlocal

 @if (@X)==(@Y) @end JScript comment */ 
 var sh=new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell"); 
 if (sh.AppActivate(WScript.Arguments.Item(1)) == 0) {
 sh.SendKeys("% r"); 
 }
```

Comment: Use an else statement, then launch Outlook, and use a goto statement to attempt to detect the process again

Answer (score 1):

Launch Outlook.exe with the START command.

```
if "%pid%" == "" ( start "" /b "full_path\to\Outlook" ) else etc.
```

This will start Outlook in a separate process from the batch file so the batch file itself will simply continue (and proceed to the exit statement).

Comment: Follow the modification, the batch can close but the newly outlook does not bring to front !!

Comment: the batch remain opened in blank